# Searching for a latching relay that can operate off 1 switch that may stay on at times

Tags: automotive, latching-relay

I am looking for a relay (latching?) for an automotive application that will allow me to switch between opened and closed, retaining its setting when power is lost, that can also handle being energized for an extended period of time.

Basically operation would look like: coil/relay is open, applying power to trigger closes coil (power may continue to stay on), removing power leaves coil in last state, next time power is applied coil opens, repeat cycle.

It seems many latching relays are designed to be used with a momentary switch. Is there some sort of relay or circuit that can accomplish what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

> coil/relay is open, applying power to trigger closes coil(power may continue to stay on), removing power leaves coil in last state, Next time power is applied coil opens, repeat cycle.

You can use an MCU to store the state in its flash/EEPROM and manage the flow each power up.

Or you can use a few numbers of single-coil latching and non-latching (ordinary) relays with some electromechanical feedback mechanism *(Single-coil relay have single coil which is used to open or close the relay contacts by applying the coil voltage in forward or reverse polarity)*:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMzFSu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Basically, latching relays (LTC_RLY1 and LTC_RLY2) are used to change the polarity of the voltage applied to the coils (assuming single coil latching relays will be used). So when the system powers up, latching relays' contacts change and keep their positions. So each time the system powers up, latching relays' coils will see the voltage in reversed polarity. Ordinary relay (RLY1) routes the supply to the 2nd latching relay at power up then disconnects after some delay to guarantee operation but **the system has a flaw**: If the delay timing and relaying timing is not precise then the latching relay contacts will constantly be changing positions which can be really annoying. Or **it can be flawless** if you can manage to cut RLY1's power right at the time the latching relays changed their positions (controlled timing). So the above is a terrible idea because it requires precise timing. Try at your own risk :)

NOTE: I just wanted to draw this to show how an MCU makes the life easier.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit should satisfy your requirement.

[image]

The following would be required:

1. A single-coil magnetic latch relay that changes state and retains it with
   alternate pulses of reverse polarity.
2. An SPDT toggle switch.
3. An electrolytic capacitor.

In one position of the toggle switch, the capacitor charge pulse sets the relay while in the other position, the discharge pulse resets it.